# A (basic) Knights and Knaves Solver

Tags: java, combinatorics

In case you're not familiar with Knights and Knaves, it's a classic type of logic problem.

Here's an example:

> "A very special island is inhabited only by knights and knaves. Knights always tell the truth, and knaves always lie.You meet two inhabitants: Zoey and Mel. Zoey tells you that Mel is a knave. Mel says, `Neither Zoey nor I are knaves.'  So who is a knight and who is a knave?"

Something that annoyed me when doing these problems was the possibility of ambiguous cases. Often, there are multiple valid solutions. Thus, my goal was to develop a program to solve problems such as this, outputting all valid possible solutions.

Main Class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class LogicDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Knights and Knaves solver! Let's quickly define the syntax.\n");
        System.out.println("Precede every statement with the name of the speaker followed by a colon, like so:\n");
        System.out.println("    Jack: I am a knave\n");
        System.out.println("There are 6 valid rule configurations. They are as follows:\n");
        System.out.println("    name: X is a [knight/knave]\n");
        System.out.println("    name: [either/neither] X [or/nor] Y is a [knight/knave]");
        System.out.println("    name: [either/neither] X is [knight/knave] [or/nor] Y is [knight/knave]\n");
        System.out.println("    name: X [and/or] Y is [knight/knave]");
        System.out.println("    name: X is [knight/knave] [and/or] Y is [knight/knave]\n");
        System.out.println("    name: X could say [any previous rule here]\n");
        System.out
                .println("There are also two additional keywords: 'not' and 'I'. The former negates the statement after it,\nand the latter refers to the current speaker.\n");
        System.out.println("With that out of the way, let's get started! Please input the statements, pressing enter after each one.\nType 'EOL' when you are finished.");
        while (!scan.hasNext("(EOL)|(eol)"))
        {
            String input = scan.nextLine();
            String[] tmp = input.split(":");
            hm.put(tmp[0].toLowerCase().trim(), tmp.length > 1 ? tmp[1].toLowerCase().trim() : "");
        }
        scan.close();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Person>> p = generatePerm(hm.keySet());
        ArrayList<Rule> ruleSet = parseRules(hm);
        System.out.println("\nRule set: " + ruleSet + "\n");
        boolean noValid = true;
        outer:
        for (ArrayList<Person> sub : p)
        {
            for (Rule r : ruleSet)
            {
                if (!r.isValid(sub))
                {
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Valid: " + sub.toString().replace("false", "is knave").replace("true", "is knight"));
            noValid = false;
        }
        if (noValid)
        {
            System.out.println("No valid solutions.");
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Rule> parseRules(HashMap<String, String> strs)
    {
        ArrayList<Rule> ar = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String key : strs.keySet())
        {
            String s = strs.get(key);
            if (s.contains("could "))
            {
                ar.add(new CouldRule(key, s));
            }
            else if (s.contains("either ") || s.contains("or ") || s.contains("and "))
            {
                ar.add(new JunctionRule(key, s));
            }
            else if (s.contains("is "))
            {
                ar.add(new IsRule(key, s));
            }
            else if (s.contains("i "))
            {
                ar.add(new SelfRule(key, s));
            }
            else
            {
                ar.add(new NullRule(key));
                System.err.println("Warning: Possibly invaild rules detected!");
            }
        }
        return ar;
    }

    //-----------------------------Permutations--------------------------------------------------
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Person>> generatePerm(Set<String> rawStrs)
    {
        ArrayList<Person> init = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : rawStrs)
            init.add(new Person(s));
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Person>> p = new ArrayList<>();
        p.add(init);
        generatePerm(p, init, 0);
        p.remove(0);
        return p;
    }

    private static void generatePerm(ArrayList<ArrayList<Person>> p, ArrayList<Person> ps, int pos)
    {
        if (pos == ps.size())
        {
            p.add(getCopy(ps));
            return;
        }
        generatePerm(p, setFalse(ps, pos), pos + 1);
        generatePerm(p, setTrue(ps, pos), pos + 1);
    }

    private static ArrayList<Person> setTrue(ArrayList<Person> ps, int ind)
    {
        ps.get(ind).isKnight = true;
        return ps;
    }

    private static ArrayList<Person> setFalse(ArrayList<Person> ps, int ind)
    {
        ps.get(ind).isKnight = false;
        return ps;
    }



    private static ArrayList<Person> getCopy(ArrayList<Person> ps)
    {
        ArrayList<Person> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Person p1 : ps)
        {
            temp.add(p1.clone());
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Rules:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Rule
{
    String self;

    public Rule(String self)
    {
        this.self = self;
    }

    abstract boolean isValid(ArrayList<Person> ps);

    public Person get(ArrayList<Person> ps, String s)
    {
        for (Person p : ps)
        {
            if (p.name.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
                return p;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class IsRule extends Rule
{
    String name;
    boolean isKnight;

    public IsRule(String self, String raw)
    {
        super(self);
        name = raw.substring(0, raw.indexOf(" "));
        if (raw.contains("not "))
        {
            isKnight = raw.contains("knight") ? false : true;
        }
        else
        {
            isKnight = raw.contains("knight") ? true : false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(ArrayList<Person> ps)
    {
        boolean invert = !get(ps, self).isKnight;
        Person p = get(ps, name);
        return invert ? !p.isKnight == isKnight : p.isKnight == isKnight;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name + " " + isKnight;
    }
}

class SelfRule extends Rule
{
    boolean isKnight;

    public SelfRule(String self, String raw)
    {
        super(self);
        if (raw.contains("not"))
        {
            isKnight = raw.contains("knight") ? false : true;
        }
        else
        {
            isKnight = raw.contains("knight") ? true : false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(ArrayList<Person> ps)
    {
        boolean invert = !get(ps, self).isKnight;
        Person p = get(ps, self);
        return invert ? !p.isKnight == isKnight : p.isKnight == isKnight;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "(self)" + self + " " + isKnight;
    }
}

class JunctionRule extends Rule
{
    String name1;
    boolean isKnight1;
    String name2;
    boolean isKnight2;
    int type = -1;

    public JunctionRule(String self, String raw)// (neither nor/either or/or/and) accounted for here
    {
        super(self);
        int ion = raw.indexOf("neither");
        if (ion >= 0) //neither nor case
        {
            type = 0;

            String tmpRaw1 = raw.substring(ion + 7, raw.indexOf("nor ")).trim();
            String[] tmpSp1 = tmpRaw1.split(" ");
            name1 = tmpSp1[0];
            name1 = name1.equals("i") ? self : name1;

            String tmpRaw2 = raw.substring(raw.indexOf("nor") + 3).trim();
            name2 = tmpRaw2.substring(0, tmpRaw2.indexOf(" "));
            name2 = name2.equals("i") ? self : name2;
            if (tmpSp1.length > 1)
            {
                if (tmpRaw1.contains("not "))
                {
                    isKnight1 = tmpRaw1.contains("knight") ? false : true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isKnight1 = tmpRaw1.contains("knight") ? true : false;
                }

                if (tmpRaw2.contains("not "))
                {
                    isKnight2 = tmpRaw2.contains("knight") ? false : true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isKnight2 = tmpRaw2.contains("knight") ? true : false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (raw.contains("not "))
                {
                    isKnight1 = raw.contains("knight") ? false : true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isKnight1 = raw.contains("knight") ? true : false;
                }
                isKnight2 = isKnight1;
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int ioe = raw.indexOf("either ");
            int ioo = raw.indexOf("or ");
            int ioa = raw.indexOf("and ");
            String tmpRaw1 = "";
            if (ioe >= 0) //either or case
            {
                tmpRaw1 = raw.substring(7, ioo).trim();
                type = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (ioo >= 0)
                {
                    tmpRaw1 = raw.substring(0, ioo).trim();
                    type = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    tmpRaw1 = raw.substring(0, ioa).trim();
                    type = 3;
                }
            }
            String[] tmpSp1 = tmpRaw1.split(" ");
            name1 = tmpSp1[0];
            name1 = name1.equals("i") ? self : name1;
            String tmpRaw2 = "";
            if (type == 2||type == 1)
                tmpRaw2 = raw.substring(ioo + 2).trim();
            else
                tmpRaw2 = raw.substring(ioa + 3).trim();
            name2 = tmpRaw2.substring(0, tmpRaw2.indexOf(" "));
            name2 = name2.equals("i") ? self : name2;

            if (tmpSp1.length > 1)
            {
                if (tmpRaw1.contains("not "))
                {
                    isKnight1 = tmpRaw1.contains("knight") ? false : true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isKnight1 = tmpRaw1.contains("knight") ? true : false;
                }

                if (tmpRaw2.contains("not "))
                {
                    isKnight2 = tmpRaw2.contains("knight") ? false : true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isKnight2 = tmpRaw2.contains("knight") ? true : false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (raw.contains("not "))
                {
                    isKnight1 = raw.contains("knight") ? false : true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isKnight1 = raw.contains("knight") ? true : false;
                }
                isKnight2 = isKnight1;
                return;

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    boolean isValid(ArrayList<Person> ps)
    {
        //not exactly D-R-Y coding here, but I think this is the clearest way to do this
        boolean invert = !get(ps, self).isKnight;
        if (type == 0)
            return invert ? (get(ps, name1).isKnight == getPerson(name1)) || (get(ps, name2).isKnight == getPerson(name2))
                    : !(get(ps, name1).isKnight == getPerson(name1)) && !(get(ps, name2).isKnight == getPerson(name2));
        if (type == 1)
            return get(ps, name1).isKnight == getPerson(name1) ^ get(ps, name2).isKnight == getPerson(name2); //XOR is its own inverse
        if (type == 2)
            return invert ? !(get(ps, name1).isKnight == getPerson(name1)) && !(get(ps, name2).isKnight == getPerson(name2))
                    : get(ps, name1).isKnight == getPerson(name1) || get(ps, name2).isKnight == getPerson(name2);
        if (type == 3)
            return invert ? !(get(ps, name1).isKnight == getPerson(name1)) || !(get(ps, name2).isKnight == getPerson(name2))
                    : get(ps, name1).isKnight == getPerson(name1) && get(ps, name2).isKnight == getPerson(name2);
        return false;
    }

    boolean getPerson(String name)
    {
        return name.equals(name1) ? isKnight1 : isKnight2;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "(Dual1) " + name1 + " " + isKnight1 + " (Dual2) " + name2 + " " + isKnight2;
    }
}

class CouldRule extends Rule
{
    String name;
    Rule r;

    public CouldRule(String self, String raw)
    {
        super(self);
        name = raw.substring(0,raw.indexOf("could ")-1);
        String s = raw.substring(raw.indexOf("could")+5);
        if (s.contains("either ") || s.contains("or ") || s.contains("and "))
        {
            r = new JunctionRule(name, s);
        }
        else if (s.contains("is "))
        {
            r = new IsRule(name, s);
        }
        else if (s.contains("i "))
        {
            r = new SelfRule(self, s);
        }
    }

    @Override
    boolean isValid(ArrayList<Person> ps)
    {
        boolean invert = !get(ps, self).isKnight;
        return invert ? get(ps,name).isKnight==false || !r.isValid(ps) : get(ps,name).isKnight==true && r.isValid(ps);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name + " " + r;
    }
}

class NullRule extends Rule
{
    //This is basically a placeholder
    public NullRule(String self)
    {
        super(self);
    }

    @Override
    boolean isValid(ArrayList<Person> ps)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return self + " placeholder";
    }
}
```

Person (basically a struct):

```
public class Person
{
    boolean isKnight = false;
    String name;

    public Person(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Person(String name, boolean isKnight)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.isKnight = isKnight;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name + " " + isKnight;
    }

    public Person clone()
    {
        return new Person(name, isKnight);
    }
}
```

Questions:

- I know the string parsing is pretty much a WTF, but is there any better way to do it besides a full-on parser?
- Is there a more efficient way to find **all** of the valid solutions?
- Does it actually work? I'm fairly sure... but testing this is a little difficult.

Finally, if you want to try it out, be sure to read the instructions first!

Comment: *"is there any better way to do it besides a full-on parser?"* No idea, but I'd suggest to remove it from this CR and assume an already parsed input. You code is a bit too long for me (OK, I'm lazy). You want to present a K&K solver, so do it... and feel free to post the parser in another CR. I'd personally prefer for CR a code piece with a test showing how to use it. Then I can modify the test in order to find bugs or test performance and this is way easier than writing any console input.

Comment: @maaartinus Well, I could do that... but the parsing is very closely tied with the Rule classes. Are you suggesting to leave those out as well, and just present the main class with a few tests?

Comment: Actually.... no idea. I had only a very brief look at the code. It looks like `Rule` contains a parser for its own string representation, which is pretty practical, however, without the class nothing can work. So it's needed for those who want to run it. This coupling could possibly be resolved (maybe by sth like `ParsingRule` extends `Rule`), but that would go too far *before* the CR. Maybe providing everything as a ZIP file for download and leaving only the important part here would be best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have answers to your questions right now, but I do have some general suggestions to make your code cleaner and more readable:

**Coding Style**

- always use curly braces, even for one-line statements to avoid bugs and to make your code easier to read.
- you are consistent with your use of `{` on the next line, which is the most important thing. But in Java, it is customary to put it on the same line, so that's what I would do.
- use spaces around `==`.

**Naming**

- `abstract` classes should have `abstract` in their name (`Rule` -> `AbstractRule`), so you can see right away that it is abstract.
- avoid short variable names, use expressive names instead. Avoid numbers in variable names (most of the time, they are a sign of bad naming). Examples: `ion`, `ioe`, `ioo`, `ioa`, `tmpRaw1`, `tmpSp1`, `name1`, `name2`, `isKnight2`, `type`, `self`, `raw`, `ps`, `hm`, `tmp`, `r`, `p`, `s`, `pos`, `ind`, etc). This might not seem that important, but it really is. Code becomes extremely hard to read if the variable names are not expressive. If I look at a method signature, I should have at least some idea what it does. This is not the case for a lot of these methods (for example `ArrayList<Person> setTrue(ArrayList<Person> ps, int ind)`).
- avoid short method names. For example, `get` should be `getPerson`.
- `getPerson` in `JunctionRule` is named wrong (it doesn't return a person, but something else instead).

**JunctionRule**

`JunctionRule` is **way** too complex. A first step to fixing this would be to extract some logic to functions (for example parsing of neither-nor, parsing of the other case).

**Dublicate Code**

Try to avoid duplicate code. For example:

- the code for checking if it is a knight is present in all `*Rule` classes.
- the `isValid` code for `IsRule`, `SelfRule` and  `CouldRule` contains a lot of duplicate code.

Another example is your `JunctionRule:isValid` method:

> ```
> @Override
> boolean isValid(ArrayList<Person> ps)
> {
>     //not exactly D-R-Y coding here, but I think this is the clearest way to do this
>     boolean invert = !get(ps, self).isKnight;
>     if (type == 0)
>         return invert ? (get(ps, name1).isKnight == getPerson(name1)) || (get(ps, name2).isKnight == getPerson(name2))
>                 : !(get(ps, name1).isKnight == getPerson(name1)) && !(get(ps, name2).isKnight == getPerson(name2));
>     if (type == 1)
>         return get(ps, name1).isKnight == getPerson(name1) ^ get(ps, name2).isKnight == getPerson(name2); //XOR is its own inverse
>     if (type == 2)
>         return invert ? !(get(ps, name1).isKnight == getPerson(name1)) && !(get(ps, name2).isKnight == getPerson(name2))
>                 : get(ps, name1).isKnight == getPerson(name1) || get(ps, name2).isKnight == getPerson(name2);
>     if (type == 3)
>         return invert ? !(get(ps, name1).isKnight == getPerson(name1)) || !(get(ps, name2).isKnight == getPerson(name2))
>                 : get(ps, name1).isKnight == getPerson(name1) && get(ps, name2).isKnight == getPerson(name2);
>     return false;
> }
> ```

It is practically unreadable and contains a lot of duplicate code. It could look something like this instead (but try to find better variable names than `b1` and `b2`, I'm just honestly not sure what they represent):

```
@Override
boolean isValid(ArrayList<Person> ps) {
    boolean invert = !get(ps, self).isKnight;
    boolean b1 = get(ps, name1).isKnight == getPerson(name1);
    boolean b2 = (get(ps, name2).isKnight == getPerson(name2));
    boolean returnValue = false;
    switch (type) {
        case 0:
            returnValue = !b1 && !b2;
            break;
        case 1:
            returnValue = b1 ^ b2; //XOR is its own inverse
            break;
        case 2:
            returnValue = b1 || b2;
            break;
        case 3:
            returnValue = b1 && b2;
            break;
    }
    if (type != 1 && invert) {
        returnValue = !returnValue;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

**Misc**

- use an enum for `type` instead of using int (and give the values a good name). Then you could also use a switch in `JunctionRule:isValid`.
- don't hardcode magic numbers. This makes it hard to change your code, and named fields would tell a reader what the number means. An example is `5` in `CouldRule` and `7` in `JunctionRule`.
- use more comments, especially JavaDoc method comments.
- your `main` should do nothing but start the program. Move your current code to functions (`help`, `readConsoleInput`, `parse`, or similar). If you follow this rule, it will be a lot easier to test your code (right now, the only way to even test it manually is to use the command line).
- `isKnight1 = tmpRaw1.contains("knight") ? false : true;` can be written as `isKnight1 = !tmpRaw1.contains("knight")`. The same idea can be applied for `return invert ? get(ps,name).isKnight==false` which should be `return invert ? !get(ps,name).isKnight`.
- use interfaces instead of concrete implementations in method signatures/variable declarations (`ArrayList` -> `List`).
- use `private` for fields, then use getter if you need to read them from outside the class.
- use `@Override` annotation when overriding a method (eg `toString`).
- if condition statements with the ternary operator get too long, they get hard to read. For example in `JunctionRule:isValid`, it would be better to use a normal `if` statement.
- the use of `goto`/`continue label` is strongly discouraged, try to change it to something else.

Comment: Thanks! The `isValid()` change you made is dramatically more readable! I think sometimes my love-affair with ternary operators goes too far.. Very fair criticism about the variable names as well. The `JunctionRule` constructor is indeed a bit too complex, something I certainly grappled with when I was debugging it.

Answer (score 1):

This is no review, just a lengthy hint: You need to decouple the code, so that it can be understood and tested. In your tests you could use expressions like

```
said(N, isKnight(X))
said(N, noKnight(X))
said(N, bothKnights(X, Y))
said(N, noKnights(X, Y))
said(N, exactlyOneKnight(X, Y))
said(N, atLeastOneKnight(X, Y))
said(K, said(L, said(M, said(N, isKnight(X)))
```

As you can see, I left out all Knaves (who cares about knaves?;) as they can be handled via some trivial preprocessing during parsing. The above is valid Java, all you need is to define a few static methods and import them. It's called embedded or internal [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language).

With a corresponding `toString`, testing gets pretty easy. From here, the next step would be some normalization. IIUIC, my last row is equivalent to

```
oddNumberOfKnights(K, L, M, N, X)
```

I'm not claiming that this representation is optimal, but something similar should help.